# Need to adjust Excel VBA macro to remove duplicates using unique identifier

Tags: vba, excel

The code I have below works well for copying/pasting from one sheet to another, but I know want to add the additional provision of deleting duplicate rows based on a unique identifier in a single column.  In column B of the sorted data is a unique identifier that can be used as a single reference to delete duplicate rows.

```
Sub SummarySort()

    Dim sEnd As Long

    Sheets("Summary").Range("A2:E250").ClearContents

    Sheets("Portfolio").Select

        Range("a1").Select

        sEnd = Selection.End(xlDown).Row

        Range("B5:" & "F" & sEnd).Copy

    Sheets("Summary").Select

        Range("A2").Select

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



        Columns("A:Z").Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
                            key2:=Range("E:E"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
                            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `Columns("A:Z").removeduplicates 2` doesn't work?

Comment: It's just that easy for some!  Thanks for the quick response, works perfectly

Comment: btw, you've got one too many `Header:=xlYes` in your sort operation. It only needs to be there once.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code line,

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

... with this code line.

```
columns("A:Z").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlyes
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, saved me a ton of time